# Regular expression

Tags: r

```
> y <- "<dd> Hello world hello i love you hello birthday thank you I am fine and you"
> regexpr("[H|h]ello", y)
[1] 6
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
> regexpr("[H|h]ello(.*)", x)
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 65
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

In the case above, what does (.*) mean? Is it regular expression or something else?

Comment: Check out https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ and regex101.com to learn about RegEx.  Specifically in this case "." means any character and "*" means 0 or more times.  So ".*" means any character 0 or more times

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a regular expression.  In a regular expression, `.` represents "any character".  * means "occuring zero or more times".  So The regex `"[H|h]ello(.*)"`  Means a string of chracaters that starts with either "H" or "h" and is followed by the exact sequence of characters "ello" and which may or may not be followed by an arbitrary sequence of characters of any length.  The brackets, `(` and `)` around the `.*` mean that the arbitrary sequence of characters is "captured" by the regex so that it can be used elsehwere.

In lay language, the purpose of the regex is to find out what you are saying after you've said hello